# Unit Testing with JUnit in JNDI datasource Hibernate with weblogic environment?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, weblogic, jndi

i am using datasource in weblogic server and, using the datasource in Hibernate.
With HibernateUtil class am getting the SessionFactory, now i want write test cases for my DAO layer by using JUnit.

1. How to get the SessionFactory in my Test class.
2. I am able to get the datasource by jndi lookup in setUp method in my Test Class

is there any better way of writing test classes in this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the datasource JNDI, using javax.naming.InitialContext. But I think wouldn't be a good idea make the test dependent on container (weblogic).

I had only 2 ideas:

- You could use Mock, getting a fake conection to DB.
- Or you could use a diferent hibernate configuration file for tests. This way, you can specify the connection directly, without JNDI.

Loading this test-file-configuration can be done using reflection or a mock.